# Composition of two invertible linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Prove or disprove:
>
> Let $A,B: {\Bbb R}^n \rightarrow {\Bbb R}^n$ be linear. If $A,B$ are both invertible, then $A\circ B$ is invertible

Can someone explain if this is true or false? I'm trying to come up with examples but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Do you mean $A \circ B$ ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.